# Retrieve customer data by date

Tags: square-connect

Can I retrieve customer data by specifying date conditon in the sqaure conect api call like :

https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers?begin_time=2016-01-15T00:00:00Z&end_time=2016-01-31T00:00:00

Same I need for orders and transactions

Answer (score 0):

No, The customers endpoint does not have any date windowing query parameters like transactions does. 
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listcustomers